# airflow webserver suddenly stopped after long time of no issues, "No response from gunicorn"

Tags: airflow

Have had `airflow webserver -D` deamon process (v1.10.7) running on machine (CentOS 7) for long time. Suddenly saw that the webserver could no longer be accessed and checking the `airflow-webserver.log` saw...

```sh
[airflow@airflowetl airflow]$ cat airflow-webserver.log
2020-10-23 00:57:15,648 ERROR - No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds
2020-10-23 00:57:15,649 ERROR - Shutting down webserver
```

(nothing of note in `airflow-webserver.err`)

```sh
[airflow@airflowetl airflow]$ cat airflow-webserver.err
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
```

The `airflow.cfg` values for the webserver section looks like...

```sh
[webserver]
# The base url of your website as airflow cannot guess what domain or
# cname you are using. This is used in automated emails that
# airflow sends to point links to the right web server
#base_url = http://localhost:8080
base_url = http://airflowetl.co.local:8080

# The ip specified when starting the web server
web_server_host = 0.0.0.0

# The port on which to run the web server
web_server_port = 8080

# Paths to the SSL certificate and key for the web server. When both are
# provided SSL will be enabled. This does not change the web server port.
web_server_ssl_cert =
web_server_ssl_key =

# Number of seconds the webserver waits before killing gunicorn master that doesn't respond
web_server_master_timeout = 120

# Number of seconds the gunicorn webserver waits before timing out on a worker
#web_server_worker_timeout = 120
web_server_worker_timeout = 300

# Number of workers to refresh at a time. When set to 0, worker refresh is
# disabled. When nonzero, airflow periodically refreshes webserver workers by
# bringing up new ones and killing old ones.
worker_refresh_batch_size = 1

# Number of seconds to wait before refreshing a batch of workers.
worker_refresh_interval = 30

# Secret key used to run your flask app
secret_key = my_key

# Number of workers to run the Gunicorn web server
workers = 4

# The worker class gunicorn should use. Choices include
# sync (default), eventlet, gevent
worker_class = sync
```

Ultimately, just restarted the process as a daemon again (`airflow webserver -D` (should I have deleted the old `airflow-webserer.log` and `.err` files first?)), but not sure what would make this happen, since it had had no problems running for months before this.

Could anyone with more experience explain what could have happened after all this time and how I could prevent it in the future? Any issues with running dags or anything else that I should check for that this temporary unexpected shutdown of the websever may have caused?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue, and it only started (very unfrequently) when I changed the following two config parameters in the webserver.

```
worker_refresh_interval = 120
workers = 2
```

However, my parameters are also set quite differently than yours, will share them here.

```
rbac = True
web_server_host = 0.0.0.0
web_server_port = 8080
web_server_master_timeout = 600
web_server_worker_timeout = 600
default_ui_timezone = Europe/Amsterdam
reload_on_plugin_change = True
```

After comparing the two, as your settings of the two I changed were set to the default (same as me before changing them), it seems that it is a combination of more parameters.